# Another domain other than localhost?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a LAMP installed on my computer without problems.  I can go to `http://localhost` and it will by default show the contents of `/var/www` .

Is there a way to add new "domains" that refrence localhost?  For example, can I do a `http://johndesktop` and have that point to `/home/john/Desktop` folder?

I just want to use something other than the word "localhost".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can put entries in your /etc/hosts file;  the first line should look like this ->
127.0.0.1       localhost

Change it to
127.0.0.1       localhost johndesktop

Then you need to edit your apache vhosts config and add a record for johndesktop to point to the desired folder, something like this in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /home/john/Desktop
    ServerName johndesktop
    ErrorLog logs/Desktop-error_log
    CustomLog logs/Desktop-access_log common
<Directory /home/john/Desktop>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```